# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=0$ and that $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification

> > Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that
> >     $$
> > \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=0.
> > $$
> >     Then use this result to prove that $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with
> >     $$
> > b_n:=\sqrt[n]{n!}
> > $$
> >     diverges.

Okay, I think that's not too bad.

I write
$$
\frac{a^n}{n!}=\frac{a}{n}\cdot\frac{a}{n-1}\cdot\frac{a}{n-2}\cdot\ldots\cdot a
$$
and because all the factors converges to 0 resp. to $a$ (i.e. the limits exist) I can write
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}a=0\cdot 0\cdot\ldots\cdot a=0.
$$

Let $a_n:=\frac{a^n}{n!}$ and $a=1$ then
$$
b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}.
$$
Because (as shown above) $a_n\to 0$ it follows that $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to 0$, because 
$$
\lvert\sqrt[n]{a_n}\rvert\leqslant\lvert a_n\rvert\to 0\implies\lvert\sqrt[n]{a_n}\rvert\to 0
$$

and therefore $b_n\to\infty$.

---

*I think that's all*. Am I right?

Comment: This is not a correct reasoning. You first product $$\frac{a}{n}\cdot\frac{a}{n-1}\cdot\frac{a}{n-2}\cdot\ldots\cdot a $$ depends on $n$ itself, so you can **not** write that the limit is equal to $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}a=0\cdot 0\cdot\ldots\cdot a=0.
$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa I'm not sure I agree with you there. As far as I know, $0^\infty$ is not an indeterminate form. (She has - taking liberties with notation - $0^\infty\cdot a$.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw The point is not the fact that $0^\infty$ is, or not, an indeterminate form... In our product, $\frac{a}{5}, \,\frac{a}{4}, \,\frac{a}{3}, \frac{a}{2}$ will never be zero...

Comment: @OlivierOloa, you are right that the terms of the product are not zero. However they are definitely $<a$ so $\in \mathbb R$. So the first $n-1$ are equal to a real number and the $n$-th term is $\frac{a}{n} \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$. So it should be

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a}{n!}
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=n}^{n-1} \frac{a}{i} \times \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a}{n}=0
$$

I'm sure that the idea is correct, but the proof is not very rigorous, because for $n \to \infty$, $n-1 \to \infty$. There probably is a way to recursively rewrite it to make it more solid, though.

Comment: @patatahooligan We are dealing with $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a^n}{n!} $ not with $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a}{n!}. $

Comment: @OlivierOloa Sorry, my first post contained a couple of typos and it seems I can't edit it anymore. It was supposed to be

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n}{n!}
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{i=n}^{n-1} \frac{a}{i} \times \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a}{n}=0
$$

Answer (score 3):

**For the first:**

$\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a^n}{n!}|\leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{m^n}{n!}\leq\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{m^n}{(n-m)!}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{m\cdot m\cdot m\cdot m...}{ (m+1)\cdot(m+2)\cdot (m+3)\cdot (m+4)...}=0$ (n factors)

Where m is (in terms of absolute value) a bigger natural number than a.

**For the second:**

Its easy so see that

$n!\geq(\frac{n}{2})^\frac{n}{2}$ (How?)

Now you obtain that:

$\sqrt[n]{n!}\geq \sqrt[n]{\frac{n}{2}^\frac{n}{2}}=\sqrt(\frac{n}{2}) \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Do not understand why $m^n/n! = m^n/(n-m)!$ and where you use the shown result to show that $b_n$ diverges.

Comment: And what if m>n?

Comment: Theres no equality, i edited it. We have $\sqrt[n]{n!}\geq \sqrt(\frac{n}{2})$. The term on the right side diverges, hence the term on the left side also diverges,as you wanted.

Comment: We want to consider the behavior of the sequence for large n. And n>m if n is large enough :)

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but not the last identity in the first row.

Comment: Why? Describe me your problem with that.

Comment: Simply do not see why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{m^n}{(n-m)!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{m\cdot m\cdot m\ldots}{(m+1)(m+2)\ldots}=0$.

Comment: Futhermore the task wants me to use the first result to prove the second. And as far as I see you showed that $b_n$ diverges, but not by the help of the first result.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not correct, because
$$|\sqrt[n]{a_n}| \leq \lvert a_n\rvert$$ is not true for $|a_n| < 1$ (in fact holds $\lvert\sqrt[n]{a_n}\rvert >\lvert a_n\rvert$).

I give you a hint. Suppose by contradiction that $b_n$ is not divergent (hence it is bounded), and call $a = \sup_{n\geq1} \sqrt[n]{n!}$. 
Then for every $n \geq 1$ you have $a^n \geq n!$.

But now, what can you say about the sequence $a_n=\frac{a^n}{n!}$? Can it be convergent to $0$?

Answer (score 1):

For the first limit, hint: Let $a$ be any real number. As $n$ tends to $+\infty,$
$$
\left|\dfrac{\dfrac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\dfrac{a^n}{n!}}\right|=\left|\dfrac{a}{n+1}\right| < \frac{1}2, \quad n\geq2|a|,
$$ and, by an elementary recursion,
$$
\left|\dfrac{a^n}{n!}\right|< \frac{C(a)}{2^n}, 
$$ as $n$ is great, where $C(a)$ is a constant in the variable $n$, and your sequence then tends to zero.

For the second limit, you may apply Riemman integral, as $n$ tends to $+\infty,$
$$\large \sqrt[n]{n!}=\displaystyle  e^{\frac1n \sum_1^n\ln k}=e^{\frac1n \sum_1^n\ln (k/n)+\ln n}\sim n \: e^{\:\Large \int_0^1\ln t \:{\rm d}t }
$$ giving a  divergent sequence.

Comment: Sorry do not understand what do you want to tell me (and if my prove is correct or not).

Answer (score 1):

Using **Stirling's formula**, both are trivial.

Comment: This is exemplary of why I dislike Stirling's approximation at the undergraduate level. To a man with a hammer every problem looks like a nail.

Answer (score 0):

If we have to conclude the second part from (the proof of) the first part, then here is one way.

Note that $a_{n+1}=\frac{a}{n+1}a_n$. So for all $\epsilon >0$ we have ${a\over n+1}<\epsilon$ for all large enough $n$. So there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $0\leq |a_{n}|\leq \epsilon^{n-k}|a_k|$ for all $n\geq k$. Fixing $\epsilon<1$, since $k$ is fixed we conclude by the squeeze theorem that $a_n\rightarrow 0$.

Now for $a\neq 0$ we further have $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}={|a|\over\sqrt[n]{n!}}\leq \epsilon^{1-{k\over n}} \sqrt[n]{|a_k|}\rightarrow \epsilon $ for all $\epsilon>0$. From this we conclude that $\sqrt[n]{n!}\rightarrow \infty$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another way to prove the first part, simply using that
$$
\exp(a)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}
$$
and this this series converges for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e. that the summands are a null sequence. That's it.

For the second part: Suppose $(b_n)_n$ does converge. Then this sequence is bounded, let's say $\lvert b_n\rvert < M$. Then by what is shown we have
$$
\frac{b_n^n}{n!}<\frac{M^n}{n!}\to 0\implies \frac{b_n^n}{n!}\to 0,
$$
but $b_n^n/n!=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative ideas:

Suppose first that $a > 0$. Then the first sequence is convergent because it is bounded below by $0$ and decreasing for $n$ large enough (how large?):
$$\frac{a^{n+1}}{(n + 1)!} = \frac{a}{n + 1}\frac{a^n}{n!} < \frac{a^n}{n!}.$$
Let be $L$ the limit. Taking the limit of the subsequence:
$$
L = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{n+1}}{(n + 1)!} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n + 1}\frac{a^n}{n!} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n + 1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!} =
0 L = 0.
$$
The general case ($a\in\mathbb R$) can be proven by sandwiching (how?).

The second limit can be calculated taking $\log$ and using [Stolz–Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$
\log\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n!} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\sqrt[n]{n!} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log 1 + \log 2 + \cdots + \log n}n = \cdots
$$