# Calculus sequences And series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find the values of $x$ for which the series $\sum_o^\infty \frac {(x+3)^n}{2^n}$ converges.

I took it as $(\frac {x+3}2)^n$ then used the rule of summation of $r^n= \frac 1{1-r}$ then found $-1<r<1$ but I'm lost

Also. How can I prove the sequence $\frac {(-3)^n}{n!}$ converges to $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Part 1.

The series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^n $ is **convergent** if and only if $|t|<1$ giving
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^n =\frac{1}{1-t}. \tag1$$ 
Thus putting $t:=\frac{x+3}{2}$ in $(1)$, we see that we must have $|x+3|<2$ equivalently $ -5<x<-1$, giving
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x+3}{2}\right)^n =\frac{1}{1-\frac{x+3}{2}}=-\frac{2}{x+1}. \tag1$$

Part 2. **Hint.**  [Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=0$ and that $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ diverges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930778/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-fracann-0-and-that-sqrtnn-diverges/930782#930782)

Comment: Thanks. For the first part how would I find the sum of the series for the values of x? Would I go through each singly?